# Forma de salvar somente duas informações

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho em meu projeto uma nova regra de negócio.

Preciso que em uma *view* de detalhes, eu tenha um pequeno formulário para salvar apenas duas informações: Atrasos e Sem Uniforme.

Eu já tenho a tabela feita. Mas eu precisava que esse form salvasse apenas essas duas informações, e não todo o objeto, até porque ele é já é carregado na página de detalhes.

Como posso fazer uma *action* que salve apenas essas informações ?

O que já tenho é isso:

```
 public ActionResult Controle([Bind(Include = "AlunoID,Atrasos,SemUniforme")] Aluno aluno)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Alunos.Add(aluno);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return View(aluno);
    }
```

Mas não sei se está certo... Por isso ainda nem fiz o `form`.

Alguém poderia me ajudar ?

Comment: O objeto a ser salvo já existe ou você está criando ele pelo formulário?

Comment: Já existe já Cigano. Até porque eu busco as informações na *view* de detalhes pra mostrar as informações para o usuário. Eu queria só adicionar essas informações ao objeto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como é uma atualização, está errado adicionar o objeto no contexto. É preciso recuperar o objeto antigo e atualizar campo a campo:

```
public ActionResult Controle([Bind(Include = "AlunoID,Atrasos,SemUniforme")] Aluno aluno)
{
    var alunoOriginal = db.Alunos.SingleOrDefault(x => x.AlunoID == aluno.AlunoId);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        alunoOriginal.Atrasos = aluno.Atrasos;
        alunoOriginal.SemUniforme = aluno.SemUniforme;
        db.Entry(alunoOriginal).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return View(alunoOriginal);
}
```